# Get current object ID in Generic DAO. Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-generic-dao

I want to delete all objects by their IDs in Hibernate Generic Dao implementation.

For now I created method like this:

```
  @Override
    public void deleteByIds(Collection<Serializable> ids) {
        getSession()
                .createQuery("delete from " + getDomainClass() + " where id in (:ids)")
                .setParameter("ids", ids)
                .executeUpdate();
    }
```

but `id` propery in query is undefined. It's mean I can have this method only on entities using `@NamedQueries` and it impossible to extract this method to Generic DAO?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` is available in your hibernate entity, you need to change

```
setParameter("ids", ids)
```

to

```
setParameterList("ids", ids)
```